# Graphical SSH - SFTP Manager for Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, ssh, sftp

I was on windows for a long time. and I installed Ubuntu 19.10 now. I was using **Bitvise ssh** and **Mobaxterm** for manage my servers in Windows.

In Ubuntu I searched a lot, but I can not find application like **Bitvise ssh** or **Mobaxterm**.

I just want an application that have these simple features:

- Sync automatically files on change (when I edit file in server) without asking for confirmation for override, etc.
- Bookmarks for saving count of servers with password (easy connection)
- Have a simple terminal (SSH Connection)
- Not too old.

Just like **Bitvise ssh**

I know wine. If you want to suggest that to use bitvise ssh in linux I say its my last way.

I tried Ubuntu default file manager as sftp client, and its need confirmation at file change and override every time and takes too time to upload.

Comment: Why? Sorry, may seem like a stupid question, but on Ubuntu you have the ability to use `sshfs` and so you can literally use whatever file manager you like. No special client required if you mount the remote folder onto a local one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a recently developed application which may be suited to your requirements: https://github.com/subhra74/snowflake

From the Github repository's description:

*Snowflake is a graphical SSH client. It has a enhanced SFTP file browser, SSH terminal emulator, remote resource/process manager, server disk space analyzer, remote text editor, huge remote log viewer and lots of other helpful tools, which makes it easy to work with remote servers. Snowflake provides functionality similar to web based control panels but, it works over SSH from local computer, hence no installation required on server. It runs on Linux and Windows. Snowflake has been tested with serveral Linux and UNIX servers, like Ubuntu server, CentOS, RHEL, OpenSUSE, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and HP-UX.*